# Selenium looping: looping and for checking boxes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, while-loop

For the website https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1, I want to select all HISCO Occupation variables, using looping, meaning I wish to check all boxes and move through pages. To do so, I've created a list with elements to tick, with the loop to tick it, which in itself I'm not sure if it is the right method:

```
checklist = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="formData[child.id]"]')

   for elem in range(len(checklist)):
      elem.click()
```

Moreover, I need to navigate through pages by clicking next until the next button is disabled on the last page, in which case I break my loop. I've set it up as follows but I cannot even execute it. I'm not sure how to correct the syntax:

```
checklist = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="formData[child.id]"]')

nextbtn = webD.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
nextbtncond = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Next")]/parent[@class="ng-scope"]')
nextbtnbreak = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/parent[@class="ng-scope disabled"]')


while nextbtncond true:
      
   for elem in range(len(checklist)):
      elem.click()

      webD.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()

   if nextbtnbreak

      for elem in range(len(checklist)):
         elem.click()

         webD.find_element_by_link_text('Apply').click()

      break
```

I'm very unsatisfied with how this is right now, but I'm lacking the intuition to improve. Any pointers?

Thank you in advance

My setup code before this step is the following:

```
## SELENIUM SETUPfrom selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_path = r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'

webD=wd.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
webD.get('https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1')


## STEP 1: SELECTING A YEAR, HERE 1851

webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/section/section[1]/article[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/label/input').click()


## STEP 2: SELECTING ENGLAND

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//b[@id = "country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input'))).click()


## STEP 3: MOVE ON TO VARIABLES

webD.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div/section/section[1]/article[2]/div/div/button').click()


## STEP 4.1: COUNTIES, OPEN MENU

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="county_category"]/button[1]'))).click()


## STEP 4.2 COUNTIES, MORE VARIABLES
WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="county_category"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()

## VERSION 1, SELECTION 1 COUNTY/ 1 HISCO_OCC
## STEP 4.3 COUNTIES, SELECT VARIABLES

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/label/input'))).click()

## STEP 4.3.2 CLICK APPLY

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Apply')]"))).click()


# STEP 5, HISCO OCCUPATION, OPEN MENU

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class = "ice-allow-download-alert ng-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active"]')))

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(
    EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class = "ice-allow-download-alert ng-animate ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active"]')))

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//b[text()[contains(.,"HISCO classified occupation")]]/..'))).click()

# SELECT MORE VARIABLE

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="workhistoryunit_category"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
```

Comment: include exception(s) you receive with your current code.

Comment: @pcalkins what do you mean? What does this do? Thanks

Comment: try/catch your driver calls... in the catch you can check the exception thrown.  That tells you something about what is wrong.